# Pandas read excel sheet with multiple header when first column is empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet like this:

[image: Excel sheet]

I want to read it with pandas read_excel and I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=[0,1])
```

but it throws me this error:

> ParserError: Passed header=[0,1] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Merged Cells for `Header 1` and `Header 2`? If yes, try to go without them.

Comment: I gotta say it was kind of a let-down after that title when i realized that this question had nothing to do with large black and white bears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind massaging the DataFrame after reading the Excel you can try the below two ways:

```
>>> pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", usecols = "B:F", skiprows=[0])
  header1 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 header2 Unnamed: 4
0    col1       col2       col3    col4       col5
1       a          0          x       3          d
2       b          1          y       4          e
3       c          2          z       5          f
```

In above, you'd have to fix the first level of the MultiIndex since header1 and header2 are merged cells

```
>>> pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", header=[0,1], usecols = "B:F", 
skiprows=[0])
        header1      header2
header1    col1 col2    col3 col4
a             0    x       3    d
b             1    y       4    e
c             2    z       5    f
```

In above, it got pretty close by skipping the empty row and parsing only columns (B:F) with data. If you notice, the columns got shifted though...

*Note* Not a clean solution but just wanted to share samples with you in a post rather than a comment

-- Edit based on discussion with OP --

[Based on documentation for pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), `header[1,2]` is creating a MultiIndex for your columns. Looks like it determines the labels for the `DataFrame` depending on what is populated in Column A. Since there's nothing there... the index has a bunch of `Nan` like so

```
>>> pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", header=[1,2])
    header1           header2
       col1 col2 col3    col4 col5
NaN       a    0    x       3    d
NaN       b    1    y       4    e
NaN       c    2    z       5    f
```

Again if you're okay with cleaning up columns and if the first column of the xlsx is always blank... you can drop it like below. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

```
>>> pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", header[1,2]).reset_index().drop(['index'], level=0, axis=1)
  header1           header2
     col1 col2 col3    col4 col5
0       a    0    x       3    d
1       b    1    y       4    e
2       c    2    z       5    f
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As you say it is pretty close, but I need the column names to be in the right place. I found trying that this works as expected: df = pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", header=[1,2]).reset_index(drop=True). I don't know exactly why it works with that header parameter.

Comment: I think this should do the job `pd.read_excel("/tmp/sample.xlsx", header[1,2]).reset_index().drop(['index'], level=0, axis=1)`

Comment: I've also modified the original post with my interpretation and understanding of the documentation for `read_excel`'s `header` parameter. Hopefully others can chime in to clarify our understanding.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) is the documentation on the `header` parameter:

> Row (0-indexed) to use for the column labels of the parsed DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed those row positions will be combined into a MultiIndex. Use None if there is no header.

I think the following should work:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", skiprows=2, usecols='B:F', header=0)
```

Comment: @OP this is a good solution if you're okay with dropping Header 1 and Header 2.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I need Header 1 and Header 2. And what about if I don't know exactly how many columns there are? It can change, so I can't use usecols ='B:F'

Comment: @AlexandraEspichán were you able to find solution on this? I am looking for something similar.